# Script fails to keep clicking on load more button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in Python in association with selenium to keep clicking on `MORE` button to load more items until there are no new items left to load from a webpage. However, my below script can click once on that `MORE` button available on the bottom of that page.

***[Link to that site](https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup&company_types[]=Private+Company&company_types[]=Mobile+App&locations[]=1688-United+States)***

This is my try so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup&company_types[]=Private+Company&company_types[]=Mobile+App&locations[]=1688-United+States"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)
while True:
    for elems in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".results .name a.startup-link"))):
        print(elems.get_attribute("href"))

    try:
        loadmore = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='more']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", loadmore)
        loadmore.click()
    except Exception:break

driver.quit()
```

How can I keep clicking on that `MORE` button until there are no such button left to click and parse the links as I've already tried using `for loop`.

Comment: Remove try catch block you provide error you're getting. Change visibility wait to clickable and try again. Also change your locator to `.more` - just simplier

Comment: If I use `.more` instead of `[class='more']`, the loop will be infinite and will never break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem pursuing sir Andersson's logic within my exising script. This is what the modified script look like.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup&company_types[]=Private+Company&company_types[]=Mobile+App&locations[]=1688-United+States"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)
while True:
    try:
        loadmore = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='more']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loadmore)
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(loadmore))
    except Exception:break

for elems in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".results .name a.startup-link"))):
    print(elems.get_attribute("href"))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Just move `for elems in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".results .name a.startup-link"))): print(elems.get_attribute("href"))` out of `while` loop and execute it in the end of script

Comment: Yep, It did the trick perfectly @sir Andersson. I would gladly take out my answer and accept yours  if you post one. Thanks.

Comment: It's not some kind of major improvement, so there is no need in new answer. You can just update your own solution

Answer (score 0):

why not just?

```
        while (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("more")).Count > 0)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("more")).Click();
            //Some delay to wait lazyload to complete 
        }
```

c# example. pretty sure that it can be done with python as well